# Python Error: Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matlab

I need to plot the function 'h', only if n is an odd number. I have read that I need to use the 'vectorize' function, but when I write it within the conditional, it doesn't work. And if I add the code outside the conditional, doesn't work. How can I solve the issue?

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

j = 0
h = 0
x = np.arange(-pi, pi, 0.01)

for n in range(1, 21):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        h = 0
    else:
        h = (4/(n*pi))*sin(n*x)

j = h + j

plt.plot(x, j)
plt.show()
```

If I write this code in Matlab, it works. The output is this:
'TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'.

Comment: you keep rewritting `h` in each iteration, what is the purpose of that variable?

Comment: Try using `np.sin` instead of `sin`

Answer (score 0):

As @fgacon suggested,I used `np.sin()`, the other issue is `j=h+j` is outside the loop. the code below should work fine.

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

j = 0
h = 0
x = np.arange(-pi, pi, 0.01)

for n in range(1, 21):
  if n % 2 == 0:
      h = 0
  else:
      h = (4/(n*pi))*np.sin(n*x)

  j = h + j

plt.plot(x, j)
plt.show()
```